# $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, How many functions $f:A \to A$ where x*$f(x)$ mod 3 = 0 exists

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ be a set, $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

How many functions from $A$ to $A$ exists ($f:A \to A$) 
 where 
x*$f(x)$ mod 3 = 0

So what i did :

$|f:\{3,6\}\to A|*|f:A\to \{3,6\}|={{6}^{2}}*{{2}^{6}}$

What did i do worng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've overcounted. $|f:\{3,6\}\to A|$ already considered the values of $f$ at $3$ and $6$, so you couldn't consider the values of the function there again at $|f:A\to \{3,6\}|$, where instead $A$ should've been $\{1,2,4,5\}$.

In which case the answer in your notation is $|f:\{3,6\}\to A|*|f:\{1,2,4,5\}\to \{3,6\}|$, which is indeed $6^2\cdot 2^4= |A|^{|\{3,6\}|}\cdot |\{3,6\}|^{|\{1,2,4,5\}|}$.

Answer (score 1):

The image of $1,2,4,5$ must belong to $\{3,6\}$; $f(3)$ and $f(6)$ can be any number in $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, so we have $2^4\cdot 6^2$ functions.